# Store last created model's row in memory

Tags: python, django

I am working on ajax-game. The abstract: 2+ gamers(browsers) change a variable which is saved to DB through json. All gamers are synchronized by javascript-timer+json - periodically reading that variable from DB.

In general, all changes are stored in DB as history, but I want the recent change duplicated in memory.

So the problem is: i want one variable to be stored in memory instead of DB.

Comment: This is very vague. There's a conflict between "duplicated in memory" and "stored in memory instead of DB." You don't describe why you want this - is it a performance issue, or a simple inability to get that item?

Comment: What stops you from doing so?

Comment: ah. I just don't know how to do it.
The main reason is performance, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the cache system:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#topics-cache

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't believe you can do this unless you only have one instance of Python running, in which case you can use a global variable.  With most web implementations you have a threaded server so this would not work.  You would have to do a fetch from the database to get the latest copy of the record.

If this is a very high-usage situation, you may want to look into [memcached](http://www.danga.com/memcached/) (or similar) as a way of lowering the performance overhead of hitting the database for each request.

Answer (score 0):

You'd either have to use a cache, or fetch the most recent change on each request (since you can't persist objects between requests in-memory).

From what you describe, it sounds as if it's being hit fairly frequently, so the cache is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like [`memcached`](http://www.danga.com/memcached/) be suitable?